# Is 你跟家人一般见面？ a yes-no question?

Tags: translation

[Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) translates

```
你跟家人一般见面？
```

as

```
When do you normally see your family?
```

However, I don't see why it is a question at all. I would translate

```
你跟家人一般见面
```

as

```
You normally see your family.
```

We can also make a question:

```
你跟家人一般见面吗？
Do you normally see your family?
```

or

```
你跟家人什么时候一般见面？
When do you normally see your family?
```

which is the translation [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) offers.

Who is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

你跟家人一般见面？ is not a correct sentence.

It should be 你跟家人一般什么时候见面？(When do you normally see your family?)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought at the end of my question - I just had the 什么时候 at the wrong position. Would the original sentence be a correct sentence if there was no question mark? "I normally see/meet my family." ==> 你跟家人一般见面.

Comment: @cheeesus 你跟家人一般见面 is wrong in any case.

Comment: What would be a translation of the statement "I normally see my family.", using 一般?

Comment: @cheeesus It can be: 我一般(这个时候)去看(我的)家人。

Answer (score 0):

When do you normally see your family?
你通常什么时候见到你的家人？